# duplicate entry: which two class are duplicate class, android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I am new in Android studio, whenever I try to add below analytics dependency to build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

and try to run project I will get always an error like

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class
```

May be because some jar file may also using above analytics library

but I can't able to figure out which  jar file is using same analytics  and because of that I am getting an error

is there any way to figure out reason?

Comment: Check this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split